# Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1
I have a "DomainEntities" table that holds the common info for all my domain entities.
I have a users table the the UserID is a Foreign Key from "DomainEntities".

see EDMX:
[image: EDMX file]

When I run the following code i get an error:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

The code:

```
static void addUserTest()
{
    DomainEntity userToAdd = new DomainEntity()
    {
        EntityName = "Test User",
        EntityTypeID = DomainEntity.eEntityType.User,
        EntityCreationDate = new DateTime(),
        EntityLastUpdateDate = new DateTime(),
        EntityCreatorUserID = 0,
        EntityUpdaterUserID = 0,
        EntityParentID = null,
        UserDetails = new User()
        {
            Username = "TestUser",
            Password = "123",
            FirstName = "Test",
            LastName = "User"

        }
    };

    using (var context = new CamelotDB())
    {
        context.DomainEntities.Add(userToAdd);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

I cant understand what is the reason that EF can understand what is the INSERT order required,
It should be One record into "DomainEntities" and then one record into "Users".
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for one more day I found it the problem was with the Creator and Updater self referenced foreign keys.

CreatorID is not Nullable so does UpdaterID and this is why EF requires the navigation properties to point to actual entities from the database so i added the following lines in the initializer of Test User.

```
EntityCreatorUserID = 0,
Creator = context.DomainEntities.Find(0),
EntityUpdaterUserID = 0,
Updater = context.DomainEntities.Find(0),
```

Comment: I had this same problem with an EF6.1 Code First schema. We changed an FK on an object that used to point to itself via a string (which is nullable) to an int. The Migration succeeded, but any attempt to save that object would explode with the vague "Unable to determine a valid ordering..." exception. Got rid of the self-reference on the class and it was solved. Interestingly the FK in the db didn't matter, just EF's awareness of it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that instead of having your `User` be related to your `DomainEntity`, you should make your `User` a *subclass* of `DomainEntity`. In the Entity Model designer, this is done by using the Inheritance tool (Double-click the Inheritance tool in the toolbox, then click once on the parent entity and once on the child entity.)

This more accurately describes the nature of a `User`; a `User` *is a* `DomainEntity`. Your current model, suggests that a `User` is *related to* a `DomainEntity`, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Sorry it has nothing to do with the relation type between User and DomainEntity. There are 2 ways to structure (Table Per Hierarchy and Table Per Type) I use the second one so i don't use inheritance. I must have something to do with the Cyclic relations in DomainEntity.